# Kafka Producer with Spring Kafka takes too long to refresh metadata when trying to produce

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices, spring-kafka

We have a standard setup with Kafka, where we use @KafkaLisetener to listen to events on a topic and send a response to another topic using KafkaTemplate.

In order to increase throughput, we increased partitions on both request and response channels to 4. After which we started seeing close to 30s lag on the message received on the response channel.

Upon further investigation of logs, we saw that a majority of that 30s is taken up by the producer trying to update metadata related to the topic it's trying to publish to.

We saw logs similar to the following (confidential information omitted)

```
2023-11-07 11:30:14.873  INFO 1 --- [tainer#61-0-C-1] i.h.microserviceName.consumer.WalletEvent  : [7e3c5513-fe7a-443f-a888-6b19b37840b2] - inside send

2023-11-07 11:30:45.013  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition microserviceName.moduleName.functionName.res-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to C85tFo-jRJWrZAvVkJnOkw
2023-11-07 11:30:45.013  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition microserviceName.moduleName.functionName.res-2 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to C85tFo-jRJWrZAvVkJnOkw
2023-11-07 11:30:45.013  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition microserviceName.moduleName.functionName.res-3 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to C85tFo-jRJWrZAvVkJnOkw
2023-11-07 11:30:45.014  INFO 1 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition microserviceName.moduleName.functionName.res-1 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to C85tFo-jRJWrZAvVkJnOkw

2023-11-07 11:30:45.014  INFO 1 --- [tainer#61-0-C-1] i.h.microserviceName.consumer.WalletEvent  : [7e3c5513-fe7a-443f-a888-6b19b37840b2] - Response sent for operation
```

The code which would generate such logs look similar to this:

```
void produce(...) {
    log.info("inside send");
    kafkaTemplate.send(....);
    log.info("Response sent for operation");
}
```

If we look at the timestamps, the log.info statements happen almost 30 seconds apart. Between which our code is completely blocked and after which we get some log statements from `org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata` specifying that some metadata was updated.

Is there any specific reason why it would take Spring Kafka 30s to update the metadata for a single topic? And is there anyway to do it in the background and not when producer is trying to produce something? So that the metadata is already ready to go.

In our use-case, the number of brokers and partitions will mostly be the same throughout so we're fine with having a bit of stale metadata as well.

We expect this process to happen quickly, there are some other microservices in our org that run on Nodejs and use the Kafkajs library and produce in a similar fashion to topics with 4 partitions, but we never face issues in those microservices.

Acceptable solutions on our end would be either can do this periodically in the background and not affect any `produce` call. Or even if Spring Kafka has to do this metadata refresh, it should happen way quicker than 30 seconds. Adding 30-second delay in any of our operations is not acceptable.